# While executing jms point to point the error is: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class:

Tags: jmeter, jms, point-to-point

The connection is not being established and the error is    javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class:com.solacesystems.jndi.SolJNDIInitialContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.solacesystems.jndi.SolJNDIInitialContextFactory]

Comment: I have added the library jndi-1.2.1.jar

Answer (score 0):

You need to add in jmeter/lib folder the jar that contains the jndi classes for your JMS implementation.

This might help:

- https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/solacesystems/sol-jms/10.0.2/sol-jms-10.0.2.pom

Comment: I have added the library jndi-1.2.1.jar

Comment: this one doesn’t contain the missing class, add the one I pointed you at

Comment: I have added both the jar files to the library including sol jms 10.3.0.jar

Answer (score 0):

You are missing sol-jms-10.3.0.jar which you can download/ use maven from [Solace JMS API](http://dev.solace.com/tech/jms-api/) site.

JMS jars need to be added to JMeter's lib folder. see [JMeter classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath):

> Other jars (such as JDBC, JMS implementations and any other support libraries needed by the JMeter code) should be placed in the lib directory - not the lib/ext directory, or added to user.classpath.

Comment: The same lib has been placed and error is still persisting

Comment: you have several libs in the zip file you download that you need to add

Comment: I have added all these libraries

Answer (score 0):

That's definitely the issue of missing dependency of SOL JMS implementation

Please add the one like (gradle example):

```
implementation 'com.solacesystems:sol-jms:10.6.3'
```